# PHP (adding value in text file )

Tags: php, text-files

I have a problem in calculating the value from the text file. I've already have a code to show the data from text file to PHP, but I need to calculate some value in the text file.

This is the value in my textfile

```
200511863:Badiola:Juan Salvador:A:88:90:85:78:94 
200510441:Peredo:Geran:G:88:90:85:78:94 
200510059:Basbas:Francis Erikson:B:88:90:85:78:94 
200311068:Ogayon:Ricky San:T:88:90:85:78:94 
200510215:Jalimao:Arvin Lowel:N:88:90:85:78:94 
200511270:Mendoza:Melvin Kenneth:M:88:90:85:78:94
```

and this is the formula:

```
 Final Grade = (Class standing *40%) + (Prelim Exam *10%) + (Midterm Exam * 20%) + (Pre-final Exam * 10%) + (Final Exam * 20%)
```

my column name are:

```
Student Id    Full Name    Class Standing    Prelim exam    midterm Exam    prefinal exam    final exam    final grade
```

and I want to do is add another column for the final grade , but I don't know how to add some value from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

The value of converting to a database is clear here (simply add a column and run a script that fills it in).

But since this is a text file, you would have no choice but to read in the text file, calculate the new value for each line and write out a new text file.

In addition, you may wish to look into PHP's [csv functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (you can set `:` as the delimiter).